# Openvpn - enabled redirect gateway but can't access any websites

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking, iptables

First of all I'm a newbie to servers but not to stuff like programming so not totally alien to command lines etc.

Second, I want to run openvpn on my remote server and connect from my ubuntu desktop to bypass geographic restrictions on things like radio and tv.

So far I've managed to do some simple tutorial setups where I can ping my remote server but now I'm having problems using the vpn for all internet activity and to NOT forward my ip on. With my current setup I can successfully ping the server but when I try to use firefox it repeatedly tries to fetch a page without moving anywhere.

One thing I think it could be is this error in my client log

```
Sat Sep 19 15:45:17 2009 us=102181 WARNING: potential route subnet conflict between local LAN [10.1.1.0/255.255.255.0] and remote VPN [10.1.1.1/255.255.255.25$
```

I did ifconfig for the client but couldn't see 10.1.1.x anywhere so don't know why it's complaining. (excuse the japanese)

Client ifconig

```
eth0      Link encap:イーサネット  ハードウェアアドレス 00:23:54:0d:37:61  
          inetアドレス:192.168.11.2  ブロードキャスト:192.168.11.255  マスク:255.255.255.0
          inet6アドレス: fe80::223:54ff:fe0d:3761/64 範囲:リンク
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  メトリック:1
          RXパケット:149701 エラー:0 損失:0 オーバラン:0 フレーム:0
          TXパケット:132252 エラー:0 損失:0 オーバラン:0 キャリア:11
          衝突(Collisions):0 TXキュー長:1000 
          RXバイト:168148922 (168.1 MB)  TXバイト:18294134 (18.2 MB)
          割り込み:251 

lo        Link encap:ローカルループバック  
          inetアドレス:127.0.0.1  マスク:255.0.0.0
          inet6アドレス: ::1/128 範囲:ホスト
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  メトリック:1
          RXパケット:68 エラー:0 損失:0 オーバラン:0 フレーム:0
          TXパケット:68 エラー:0 損失:0 オーバラン:0 キャリア:0
          衝突(Collisions):0 TXキュー長:0 
          RXバイト:7608 (7.6 KB)  TXバイト:7608 (7.6 KB)

tun0      Link encap:不明なネット  ハードウェアアドレス 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inetアドレス:10.1.1.6  P-t-P:10.1.1.5  マスク:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  メトリック:1
          RXパケット:4 エラー:0 損失:0 オーバラン:0 フレーム:0
          TXパケット:4 エラー:0 損失:0 オーバラン:0 キャリア:0
          衝突(Collisions):0 TXキュー長:100 
          RXバイト:336 (336.0 B)  TXバイト:336 (336.0 B)
```

Could it be that error? And if so how do I work around it. Failing that I'm not sure what it could be so here are my config files

Client config

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote ***.***.**.*** 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
ns-cert-type server
cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo
status /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log /etc/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 5
```

Server conf

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh1024.pem
server 10.1.1.0  255.255.255.128
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 3
```

iftables for serverChain INPUT (policy DROP 1 packets, 40 bytes)

```
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  199 14380 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
  333 64149 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
   11   924 ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  venet0 any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:openvpn 
    6   360 ACCEPT     tcp  --  venet0 any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:openvpn 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   27  1620 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   venet0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  venet0 tun0    anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 441 packets, 50749 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   11   924 ACCEPT     all  --  any    tun+    anywhere             anywhere
```

finally the client logs with my server ip commented out

```
     pkts bytes taSat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=410978 Current Parameter Settings:
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411095   config = 'client.conf'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411117   mode = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411134   persist_config = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411151   persist_mode = 1
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411168   show_ciphers = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411185   show_digests = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411201   show_engines = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411217   genkey = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411233   key_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411249   show_tls_ciphers = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411268 Connection profiles [default]:
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411285   proto = tcp-client
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411301   local = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411317   local_port = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411334   remote = '***.***.**.***'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411350   remote_port = 1194
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411366   remote_float = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411382   bind_defined = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411398   bind_local = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411415   connect_retry_seconds = 5
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411431   connect_timeout = 10
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411447   connect_retry_max = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411464   socks_proxy_server = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411480   socks_proxy_port = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411496   socks_proxy_retry = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411515 Connection profiles END
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411531   remote_random = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411548   ipchange = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411564   dev = 'tun'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411580   dev_type = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411596   dev_node = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411612   lladdr = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411628   topology = 1
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411644   tun_ipv6 = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411661   ifconfig_local = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411677   ifconfig_remote_netmask = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411694   ifconfig_noexec = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411710   ifconfig_nowarn = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411726   shaper = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411742   tun_mtu = 1500
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411758   tun_mtu_defined = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411774   link_mtu = 1500
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411790   link_mtu_defined = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411807   tun_mtu_extra = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411823   tun_mtu_extra_defined = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411839   fragment = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411855   mtu_discover_type = -1
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411876   mtu_test = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411894   mlock = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411910   keepalive_ping = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411927   keepalive_timeout = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411943   inactivity_timeout = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411959   ping_send_timeout = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411975   ping_rec_timeout = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=411994   ping_rec_timeout_action = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412010   ping_timer_remote = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412026   remap_sigusr1 = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412042   explicit_exit_notification = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412058   persist_tun = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412074   persist_local_ip = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412090   persist_remote_ip = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412106   persist_key = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412123   mssfix = 1450
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412138   passtos = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412155   resolve_retry_seconds = 1000000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412171   username = 'nobody'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412187   groupname = 'nogroup'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412203   chroot_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412219   cd_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412248   writepid = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412265   up_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412282   down_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412298   down_pre = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412314   up_restart = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412330   up_delay = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412346   daemon = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412362   inetd = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412378   log = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412394   suppress_timestamps = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412411   nice = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412427   verbosity = 5
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412443   mute = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412459   gremlin = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412475   status_file = '/etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412491   status_file_version = 1
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412507   status_file_update_freq = 60
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412523   occ = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412540   rcvbuf = 65536
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412556   sndbuf = 65536
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412572   sockflags = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412588   fast_io = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412605   lzo = 7
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412621   route_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412637   route_default_gateway = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412653   route_default_metric = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412669   route_noexec = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412685   route_delay = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412701   route_delay_window = 30
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412717   route_delay_defined = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412733   route_nopull = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412750   route_gateway_via_dhcp = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412766   allow_pull_fqdn = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412782   management_addr = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412799   management_port = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412815   management_user_pass = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412832   management_log_history_cache = 250
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412848   management_echo_buffer_size = 100
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412864   management_write_peer_info_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412881   management_flags = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412897   shared_secret_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412914   key_direction = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412931   ciphername_defined = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412947   ciphername = 'BF-CBC'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412964   authname_defined = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412980   authname = 'SHA1'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=412996   keysize = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413012   engine = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413029   replay = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413045   mute_replay_warnings = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413068   replay_window = 64
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413085   replay_time = 15
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413102   packet_id_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413118   use_iv = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413134   test_crypto = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413151   tls_server = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413167   tls_client = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413183   key_method = 2
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413200   ca_file = 'ca.crt'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413216   ca_path = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413232   dh_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413248   cert_file = 'client1.crt'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413265   priv_key_file = 'client1.key'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413281   pkcs12_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413297   cipher_list = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413313   tls_verify = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413329   tls_remote = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413346   crl_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413375   ns_cert_type = 64
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413392   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413409   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413425   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413441   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413457   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413473   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413489   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413504   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413520   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413536   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413552   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413568   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413584   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413599   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413615   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413631   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413647   remote_cert_eku = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413664   tls_timeout = 2
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413680   renegotiate_bytes = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413696   renegotiate_packets = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413713   renegotiate_seconds = 3600
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413729   handshake_window = 60
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413745   transition_window = 3600
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413761   single_session = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413777   tls_exit = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413793   tls_auth_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413810   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413826   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413843   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413859   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413875   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413891   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413907   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413923   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413939   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413955   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413971   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=413987   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414002   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414018   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414034   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414051   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414067   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414084   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414100   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414116   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414132   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414149   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414165   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414181   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414197   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414213   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414229   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414245   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414261   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414277   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414294   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414309   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414325   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414341   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414369   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414386   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414402   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414418   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414434   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414450   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414466   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414482   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414498   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414514   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414530   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414546   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414563   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414578   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414595   pkcs11_pin_cache_period = -1
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414611   pkcs11_id = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414627   pkcs11_id_management = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414655   server_network = 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414674   server_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414691   server_bridge_ip = 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414709   server_bridge_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414726   server_bridge_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414743   server_bridge_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414760   ifconfig_pool_defined = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414777   ifconfig_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414795   ifconfig_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414812   ifconfig_pool_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414828   ifconfig_pool_persist_filename = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414849   ifconfig_pool_persist_refresh_freq = 600
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414867   n_bcast_buf = 256
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414883   tcp_queue_limit = 64
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414899   real_hash_size = 256
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414915   virtual_hash_size = 256
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414932   client_connect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414948   learn_address_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414965   client_disconnect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414981   client_config_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=414997   ccd_exclusive = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415014   tmp_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415030   push_ifconfig_defined = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415047   push_ifconfig_local = 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415065   push_ifconfig_remote_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415081   enable_c2c = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415098   duplicate_cn = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415114   cf_max = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415131   cf_per = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415147   max_clients = 1024
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415164   max_routes_per_client = 256
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415180   client_cert_not_required = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415196   username_as_common_name = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415213   auth_user_pass_verify_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415229   auth_user_pass_verify_script_via_file = DISABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415245   port_share_host = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415262   port_share_port = 0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415278   client = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415294   pull = ENABLED
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415311   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=415328 OpenVPN 2.1_rc11 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] built on Mar  9 2009
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=416184 /usr/bin/openssl-vulnkey -q -b 1024 -m <modulus omitted>
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=542574 LZO compression initialized
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=542740 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:140 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=542839 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:1450 EF:44 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=542877 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1544,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=542895 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1544,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_SERVER,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=542929 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '69109d17'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=542954 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'c0103fa8'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=543531 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Sat Sep 19 16:12:03 2009 us=543582 Attempting to establish TCP connection with ***.***.**.***:1194 [nonblock]
Sat Sep 19 16:12:04 2009 us=543727 TCP connection established with ***.***.**.***:1194
Sat Sep 19 16:12:04 2009 us=543788 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
Sat Sep 19 16:12:04 2009 us=543812 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Sat Sep 19 16:12:04 2009 us=543841 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: ***.***.**.***:1194
WRSat Sep 19 16:12:04 2009 us=544185 TLS: Initial packet from ***.***.**.***:1194, sid=b7baae8e 3f7be9ea
WRWWRRWRRRWWRWRWRRWWRWRWRRWWRWRWRRWWRWRWRSat Sep 19 16:12:08 2009 us=724208 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=UK/ST=GM/L=Manchester/O=YoFelix/CN=YoFelix_CA/emailAddress=adam@ca.com
Sat Sep 19 16:12:08 2009 us=724381 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Sat Sep 19 16:12:08 2009 us=724404 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=UK/ST=GM/L=Manchester/O=YoFelix/CN=server/emailAddress=adam@ca.com
RWWRWRWRRWWWWWRWRRRWWWRWRWRRWWRWRWRRWWRWRWRRWWRWRRRRWWWWRRRRRRSat Sep 19 16:12:14 2009 us=580994 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Sep 19 16:12:14 2009 us=581035 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sat Sep 19 16:12:14 2009 us=581123 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Sep 19 16:12:14 2009 us=581143 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
WWSat Sep 19 16:12:14 2009 us=581210 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Sat Sep 19 16:12:14 2009 us=581245 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with ***.***.**.***:1194
Sat Sep 19 16:12:15 2009 us=829569 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
WRRRSat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=392662 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway,route 10.1.1.1,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.1.1.6 10.1.1.5'
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=392720 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=392738 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=392755 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=392930 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.11.1
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=393740 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=393779 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=393818 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.1.1.6 pointopoint 10.1.1.5 mtu 1500
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=397075 /sbin/route add -net ***.***.**.*** netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.11.1
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=398944 /sbin/route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=400546 /sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 10.1.1.5
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=402024 WARNING: potential route subnet conflict between local LAN [10.1.1.0/255.255.255.0] and remote VPN [10.1.1.1/255.255.255.255]
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=402073 /sbin/route add -net 10.1.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.1.1.5
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=403326 GID set to nogroup
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=403367 UID set to nobody
Sat Sep 19 16:12:16 2009 us=403388 Initialization Sequence Completed
WWrWRwrWRwrWRwrWRwWRWRrWrWrWrWrWrWRrWRWrWRrWrWrWRrWRrWRWRWrWRWRrWRWRWrWrWrWrWrWrWRrWrWRWrWRWrWRrWrWRrWRrWrWRWRrWRWRWrWRrWrWRWrWRrWRWRWrWrWRrWrWRWRrWrWRWRrWrWRWRWrWRrWrget
```

I added the nat rule to my iptables like pqd suggested and i could access web pages but very slow. I dont know if thats teh norm but i have a sneaky suspision this subnet conflict i mentioned above is causing some problems. I since tried changing my vpn network adddress to 10.2.2.0 to see if it would change anyting but the message is the same. What is this local network its talking about??? the one between my router and desktop pc?? if i do ifconfig on the local desktop i dont see any 10.2.2.?

Here is route -r

```
10.2.2.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.2.2.0        10.2.2.2        255.255.255.128 UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.0.2.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 venet0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 venet0
0.0.0.0         192.0.2.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 venet0
```

******************** YAY!!!!!!!!! *********************

Yes I got it to work and the speed has improved.

Comment: Please, add the result of
# route -n

Comment: minder ive just done so and edited my original post accordigly (see bottom).

Comment: i cannot help speed. i have very good experience with openvpn running in multiple locations between different countries... i get near ~99% of available bandwidth via encrypted tunnels - so as long as i have good internet connection between both endpoints i cannot tell the difference in performance going via pure internet vs via tunnel.

Comment: yes i think this is to do with the error 

 potential route subnet conflict between local LAN [10.2.2.0/255.255.255.0] and remote VPN [10.2.2.1/255.255.255.25$


i dont know of any subnet of 10.2.2.? on my local client. So why is it saying there is a conflict? I am sat behind a router but when I do ifconfig no network adapter shows up with that subnet range - or am i missing somethign here???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do few things

1 ensure you have pkt forwarding enabled on vpn server:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

it should be 1, if it's not run:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

2 for a good measure add [ not really needed since you allow traffic from/to tun0.. ]

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

3 and finally - nat the traffic coming from vpn - that is: replace the source ip address of your connection with address of the server

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

i think the last point is the missing one...

Comment: Thanks very much. Your advice has helped me get it working. pkt forwardiing was already on. I ammended the postrouting with the masquerade and its now fetching pages, but very slowly.

Comment: yes i think this is to do with the error potential route subnet conflict between local LAN [10.2.2.0/255.255.255.0] and remote VPN [10.2.2.1/255.255.255.25$ i dont know of any subnet of 10.2.2.? on my local client. So why is it saying there is a conflict? I am sat behind a router but when I do ifconfig no network adapter shows up with that subnet range - or am i missing somethign here???